# Laravel Eloquent LEFT JOIN WHERE NULL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to use Eloquent to perform the following query during a database seed:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    customers
LEFT JOIN
    orders
    ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE
    orders.customer_id IS NULL
```

And here is my implementation in Eloquent:

```
$c = Customer::leftJoin('orders', function($join) {
      $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id');
    })
    ->whereNull('orders.customer_id')
    ->first();
```

Whereas the first query always returns full results, the Eloquent equivalent always returns empty elements for everything but the `email` and `phone` fields of the `customers` table. I'm at a loss to explain this since the `Customers` and `Orders` models are both artisan generated skeletons.

Ex:

```
class Customer extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = [];

}
```

Here is the array that is output when I dd() the first Eloquent query on a seed (generated originally by Faker):

```
protected $original =>
  array(25) {
    'id' =>
    NULL
    'first_name' =>
    NULL
    'last_name' =>
    NULL
    'email' =>
    string(24) "luther.braun@example.org"
    'phone' =>
    string(17) "642.150.9176x5684"
    'address1' =>
    NULL
    'address2' =>
    NULL
    'city' =>
    NULL
    'state' =>
    NULL
    'county' =>
    NULL
    'district' =>
    NULL
    'postal_code' =>
    NULL
    'country' =>
    NULL
    'notes' =>
    NULL
    'created_at' =>
    NULL
    'updated_at' =>
    NULL
    'customer_id' =>
    NULL
    'total' =>
    NULL
}
```

Comment: This code runs exactly the same query as your SQL

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This can be resolved by specifying the specific column names desired from the specific table like so:

```
$c = Customer::leftJoin('orders', function($join) {
      $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id');
    })
    ->whereNull('orders.customer_id')
    ->first([
        'customers.id',
        'customers.first_name',
        'customers.last_name',
        'customers.email',
        'customers.phone',
        'customers.address1',
        'customers.address2',
        'customers.city',
        'customers.state',
        'customers.county',
        'customers.district',
        'customers.postal_code',
        'customers.country'
    ]);
```

Comment: You could also specify to get all columns something like `customers.*`

Comment: Aliases e.g. `customers.id as customer_id` are also possible for better readability.

Answer (score 19):

Although Other Answers work well, i want to give you **alternate short version** which i use very often:

```
Customer::select('customers.*')
        ->leftJoin('orders', 'customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id')
        ->whereNull('orders.customer_id')->first();
```

And as in `laravel version 5.3` added one more feature which will make your work even simpler look below for example:

```
Customer::doesntHave('orders')->get();
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also specify the columns in a select like so:

```
$c = Customer::select('*', DB::raw('customers.id AS id, customers.first_name AS first_name, customers.last_name AS last_name'))
->leftJoin('orders', function($join) {
  $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id') 
})->whereNull('orders.customer_id')->first();
```

Answer (score 6):

I would dump your query so you can take a look at the SQL that was actually executed and see how that differs from what you wrote.

You should be able to do that with the following code:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
var_dump($last_query);
die();
```

Hopefully that should give you enough information to allow you to figure out what's gone wrong.

Comment: Ran it and the queries are identical. When I run them in MySQL Workbench directly I get the expected results. This tells me the problem lies in some facet of the way Laravel handles the retrieved data.

Comment: I just realized that the NULL fields from the `orders` table row that has yet to be created are overwriting the values in the `customers` table that has values. The only difference between the `customers` and `orders` tables is that the `orders` table does not have an `email` or `phone` field, so that value is not overwritten. I've never seen this behavior before. How do I prevent Laravel's Eloquent from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would be using laravel **whereDoesntHave** to achieve this.

```
Customer::whereDoesntHave('orders')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$query = Customers::with('orders');
$query = $query->whereHas('orders', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
     $query = $query->where('orders.customer_id', 'NULL') 
});
    $query = $query->get();
```