# laravel belongsToMany with all rows of model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

I have a belongsToMany relation of user and resource.

**User:**

```
    public function resources() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Resource')->withPivot(array('value'));
    }
```

**Resource:**

```
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot(array('value'));
    }
```

the intermediate table is `resource_user`.
With:

```
$resources = Sentry::getUser()->resources()->get();
```

I get all the resources where the user_id is in the resource_user table.
so far so good.
But how can I get ALL the resources entries, even the user_id is not present at the intermediate table?
Let's say I have 3 resources in the resource Table. Id 1, 2 and 3.
I have one user with ID 1. In the intermediate Table I have ONLY 2 rows:

> resource_id 1 and user_id 1 and value 50.
>
> resource_id 2 and user_id 1 and value 100.

But I want display ALL the resources, and if the user is not present there, there should be resource object but without the relation model of the user.

`whereHas` isn't working with this problem.

so my goal is to get 3 results, and not 2.
something like this:

> resource_id 1 user_id 1 value 50
>
> resource_id 2 user_id 1 value 100
>
> resource_id 3 user_id 0 value 0

The only thing what I figured out is this:

In the resource model I create a function like this:

```
    # Get specific User value from resource
    public function userValue() {
        $res_user = DB::table('resource_user')->whereUserId(Sentry::getUser()->id)->whereResourceId($this->id)->first();
    if($res_user){
        return $res_user->value;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But I wonder there exist an cleaner eloquent way for this?
Any Idea of that?

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328301/laravel-eloquent-left-join-where-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you quite right but to get "all resources" you can just use the `Resource` model:

```
$resources = Resource::with('users')->get();
```

To only eager load the current user you can add a filtering closure:

```
$resources = Resource::with(array('users' => function($q) use ($userId){
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
}))->get();
```

Comment: the problem with your code is that I now get ALL users which are related to this resource. But I want only the current logged user related to the resource entry...

Comment: I think.. I got it:
`$resources = Resource::with(array('users' => function($q) {
            $q->whereUserId(currentUser()->id);
        }))->get();`

Comment: I see I didn't catch that part of the question... Yes that would be the best solution :) I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. that push me into the right direction.