# Laravel Eloquent: Finding objects that are missing a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Posts` object, that may or may not have a `Link` object (Link belongsTo Post and Post hasOne Link).

I'm trying to find Posts that were created after a certain date that don't have a Link created yet.

I have the following but it doesn't work:

`$posts = Post::where('post_date', '>', 'xxxx')->whereIsNull('link.id'); // which is how I would write it with an OUTER JOIN.`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried a group by and having?

Comment: I'm trying to do it entirely in Eloquent.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328301/laravel-eloquent-left-join-where-null ?

Comment: Post and Link has one to one relationship, so in `post` table there is `link_id` field to refer to Link, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Laravel eager loading and loop through the results to find posts without links.

```
$posts = Post::with('link') -> get();
// loop with foreach and extract posts with no links
$not_linked_posts = array();
foreach ($posts as $k => $post){
  // if link is not set
  if (!isset($post -> link)){
       // add it to array
       $not_linked_posts[$k] = $post -> toArray(); //convert post to array
  }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This would work, but definitely not the most efficient solution. A simple query would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: yeah the problem is, there's a few thousand posts. I'd like for most of the work to be done with MySQL. Thanks however.

Comment: @yangqi how would you do it in a simple query?