# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I keep getting this error after fixing a new code that I had just put in and I have no idea why it is giving me this error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance" which point to the id of my route in home.blade.php. Can someone help me take a look thanks a lot

The part that I added in was the hire_status part and after fixing it, it then gave me this error.
home.blade.php

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><strong><big>Name: </big></strong></th>     
        <th><strong><big>Hire Status: </big></strong></th>  
        <th><strong><big>Action: </big></strong></th>
      </tr>
      <td>
      <tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
      <tr>    
      <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
    <th> 
      @foreach($data1 as $value1)

      {{$value1->hire_status}}

   </th>
      <th><form action="{{  url('/home/'.$value->id.'/delete')  }}" method="get">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
      </form></th>              
      </tr>
      @endforeach
         @endforeach
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

HomeController:

```
    public function getData(){
        $data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
        $data1 = DB::table('hires')->where('hire_status','Yes')->get();

        if(count($data)>0){
        return view('home',compact('data','data1'));
    }else{
    return view('home');
}
}
```

Comment: print_r your $data,
can we see your $data contain?

Comment: @Rits sorry where do I put the print_r, sorry it my first time using it

Comment: just, print_r() after this `$data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');`
print_r($data);
exit;

Comment: and why are you taking array of array(key) data just remove it and check it with only $data = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->get()‌​->sortByDesc('create‌​d_at');

Comment: @Rits I have did the print_r and it contain all my data that I had saved in my database with multiple array like array[0] and array[1]

Comment: now remove this that i have told. and check. everything is working or not

Comment: Yup it work thank you so much, could you maybe put your answer below and I will upvote it

Comment: welcome brother i have posted my answer there.
and tnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove key from array,
you are trying to get data in your view directly so get it directly not to data of data...

```
$data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->get()‌​->sortByDesc('create‌​d_at');
```

change it to,

```
$data = DB::table('personal_infos')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->get()‌​->sortByDesc('create‌​d_at');
```

Comment: sorry to disturb you again but why is my home.blade.php only displaying yes for the hire_status when one of my datas is no

Comment: sorry i had lunch.
because you are retrieving only those records which have hire_status only yes, `$data1 = DB::table('hires')->where('hire_status','Yes')->get();`
see your where condition `where('hire_status','Yes')` so that it will not fetch the data with hire status No.

Comment: Yup that is what I want. Hmm maybe I give you an example of what happen, jack is hired so he is under yes, but jane is not hired so she is under no but when I see the whole view, they show me both jane and jack are hired(both are yes)

Comment: yup because the queries are seperate.
thats why. you can use join query for retrieve only those which have yes.
join the both table in one query

Comment: Wait do you understand what I mean? I just want to see yes result but one of the user is no, and in that result that user is being shown and is under yes even though it original is no

Comment: So I need to join both personal_info table and hires table together inside the HomeController?

Comment: [Joining tables] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328301/laravel-eloquent-left-join-where-null)
you can find in laravel tutorials also.

Comment: Yup just saw it so all I have to do is just join personal_info and hires table together inside the HomeController? Is it?

Comment: yup... absolutely

Comment: and if any query then google and stackoverflow are 24*7 with us :)

Comment: I have tried doing by using this but it gave me the same result, "        $data1 = DB::table('hires')
            ->join('personal_infos', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'hires.user_id')
            ->select('hires.hire_status')
            ->where('hire_status','Yes')
            ->get();"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157871/discussion-between-rits-and-blastme).

Comment: If I remove the where part I will get all no so I am kind of confused what is happening, is it my home.blade.php problem

Comment: sorry about that just reach home, shall we continue in chat? @Rits